# How to convert a bitmap font (.FON) into a truetype font (.TTF)?

Tags: fonts, truetype, bitmap-fonts

My program (win32, Delphi) needs to display special chars in some columns of a table. To do that I use a special font for those columns. I got the font from my client. It is a .FON font. It works good on the screen but I often get problems as soon as I want to use it to print something.

I would like to convert this .FON font into to truetype font (.TTF) to avoid the problems. I don't care if the font does not scale good. I should just looks exactly the same when used on the screen with the same size as the default size of the original font.
Do someone know a way to do that?

(It don't necessary need a source code solution. The font won't change. It's enough if I find a tool to do it)

**Edit:** Ideal would be to get a truetype font where each pixel of the original font is converted into a vectorial black square (I tested by redrawing a few chars manually, it would works as I want).

**Edit 2, solution used:** Using [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) + [Autotrace](http://sourceforge.net/projects/autotrace/) and then making corrections manually I was able to get a vector font that follow the outline of the pixels of the bitmap font. This vector font scales somewhat better than the original font and solve my printing problems. See accepted post for details.

But I'm still interested if someone knows a fully automated solution.

Comment: did you use those on windows or linux ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) + [Autotrace](http://sourceforge.net/projects/autotrace/) then make some corrections manually.

First integrate Autotrace in Fontforge, see [Autotracing bitmaps in FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/autotrace.html). Here is how I have done it, as I wasn't able to use the win32 version of FontForge:

1. Download, unzip and start [Portable Ubuntu Tres](http://portableubuntu.sourceforge.net/). It's a special linux version that works under Windows!
2. Choose System->Administration->Add/Remove Applications, search for FontForge and install it (administrator password is 123456). I got FontForge version 20090622 installated.
3. Download autotrace-0.31.1.tar.gz from http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/index.html#download and copy it in your home directory in Portable Ubuntu.
4. In Portable Ubuntu choose Applications->Accessories->Terminal to compile and install autotrace:

   ```
   sudo bash  (password is 123456)
   gunzip autotrace-0.31.1.tar.gz
   tar xf autotrace-0.31.1.tar
   cd autotrace-0.31.1
   ./configure
   make
   make install
   ```

Then convert your font:

1. Start FontForge in Portable Ubuntu and open the .FON font.
2. Save your font as a .BDF font (Loading a .FON file as background didn't work for me so I had to convert the font first): File->Generate Fonts and choose BDF as format.
3. Create a new font and import the BDF Font as background font: File->Import and don't forget select "As Background".
4. Select all characters and start an autotrace while holding the shift key so that you can enter parameters for autotrace. I used following parameters, which improved the recognition of the outline of the pixels but I didn't found the perfect parameters:

   ```
   -corner-surround=1 -line-threshold=10
   ```
5. Correct the chars manually using mostly the function "Add a curve point".
   Activating View->Show->Almost Horizontal/Vertical Lines makes the work much easier.
6. Generate a truetype font: File->Generate Fonts and choose truetype as format.

Comment: Portable Ubuntu doesn't exist anymore, but it is possible to do the same thing with a real Linux installation (eventually in a virtual machine)

Comment: autotrace is unmaintained, but you can install potrace which acts as a drop-in replacement. Be sure to choose "Prefer potrace" in the FontForge Preferences dialog, since ff won't detect potrace on its own.

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is old, but for what it is worth I was able to easily convert an old .fon to .ttf using [PixFont](http://www.kgroup.ru/products.html). I ran it as an administrator (no installs - an old school executable in place) and it generated a good TTF even though the original .fon was missing some correct glyphs.

And, while it isn't free, at $29 it almost is, especially compared to the very expensive commercial products out there.

Comment: This actually worked! Installing and using FontForge was difficult. This tool got the job done with only a few clicks.

Answer (score 6):

For those that do not want to compile fontforge (for windows) grab a download here:
http://www.mpetroff.net/software/fontforge-windows/

That build uses potrace instead of autotrace. The best parameters I got for the font that I was converting (vgasys.fon) were:

`--turdsize 0 --opttolerance 0 --unit 1 --longcurve --gamma 0 --blacklevel 0 --cleartext`

It was still hours of manual work to get the font looking good (by adding and removing points).

Comment: gotta love a program that has an option called "turdsize". hehe.

Comment: Good point as "Portable Ubuntu Tres" seems to have disappeared... And thanks for the params.

Comment: Meanwhile the Windows version of FontForge including potrace is avaible on the official FontForge website: http://sourceforge.net/projects/fontforge/

Answer (score 5):

Using [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) I was able to generate a corresponding truetype font, which gives exactly the same chars as the original font when used at the good size. May be I still need to tweak some options, because I used my original font at size=11. The new font works good only at size=10.5, which is impossible to use in delphi. The font looks really horrible at every other size.

1. Load the .FON font in FontForge
2. Choose File->Generate Fonts
3. Select "(faked) MS bitmap only sfnt (ttf)" as type, entre a file name and click "save".

Apparently it uses a possibility to store bitmap fonts in a truetype-font. The resulting font doesn't have the problems I had with the bitmap fonts, but it is completly blank on the printer so that it doesn't solve my problem.

**A note about [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/):**
*I didn't manage to install the Windows Version of FontForge (based on cygwin). Instead of that I Installed [Portable Ubuntu Tres](http://portableubuntu.sourceforge.net/), which is a linux version that works on Windows. It's easy to install: unzip the file and start the exe. Then choose System->Administration->Add/Remove Applications and search for FontForge and install it (administrator password is 123456). I got FontForge version 20090622 installated.*

Answer (score 3):

I found that the easiest route to getting a good TTF version of a FON is to use one of the free online bitmap font editors. You have to manually enter each glyph, but the process is much simpler than coming to grips with FontForge. There are two editors that I know of, and they both produce TTFs that work fine on Windows and Linux.

[BitFontMaker](http://www.pentacom.jp/pentacom/bitfontmaker2/) is the simpler of the two. I like its clean interface, but I ended up not using it because monospaced fonts can only have cell widths of 10 to 14 pixels.

[FontStruct](http://fontstruct.com/) requires registration and uses a Flash interface. I was able to make new fonts quite fast once I got used to the interface. (It might be coincidence, but I noticed an uptick in spam on the email account I used to register.)

Both editors set the line spacing automatically. A trick to get the spacing you want is to add a high pixel on one character, then use a vector font editor to remove it from the TTF. (*Type light* works well and is much easier to use than FontForge.)

Answer (score 3):

After hours of working with different font editors and applying the mentioned methods, they could not do the conversion well.

But, I suddenly found that Vertopal (a free file converter) has a [fon to ttf converter](https://www.vertopal.com/en/convert/fon-to-ttf) and several other font converters, it quickly converted fon to ttf with the same original characters and the correct size.

[image: Vertopal fon to ttf converter]
You can also apply custom settings to the conversion, however, these defaults did the best conversion for me.

Answer (score 2):

A possibility might be to use the command line tool [SBIT32 fom Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/tools/tools.aspx). It's easy to convert the .FON file into a .BDF file using [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/). But then you need to write a metrics file (.MET). I didn't try it, because I suppose that I would get a truetype-font with embedded bitmaps font, and it is possible to generate such fonts directly with [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) (type "(faked) MS bitmap only sfnt (ttf)" under File->Generate Fonts).

Answer (score 2):

Autotrace seems to produce a pixel perfect output, if the input is scaled, I made some tests and scaling at least 8× works perfectly.

After opening the bitmap font in FontForge, Open - > Element - > Bitmap Strikes, and create a bitmap strike of 8× the resolution (for example: if 16, then 128). Then save this bitmap strike as a bitmap font (e. g. bdf).

Perform the "Autotrace" on this scaled output.

There are more points than needed, this can be resolved by using Element\Simplify\Simplify, this will simplify the outlines. In this specific case of the outlines being made of only horizontal and vertical lines, this operation should be lossless.

It's automated, making it much easier for fonts with tons of characters than redrawing all the characters manually. This should definitely be useful for anyone who drew bitmap glyphs and has a valid bitmap font file but cannot use it yet (Microsoft's .fon format does not support Unicode, and many applications fail to properly utilize true bitmap fonts).

Comment: I didn't know it's possible to scale bitmaps like that! It also prevents the Unicode encoding from being lost, and greatly simplifies this answer.

Comment: BTW here's how to install FontForge + Potrace. Get FontForge [here](https://fontforge.org/en-US/downloads/windows-dl/), Potrace [here](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/#downloading). Then you have to add the folder where you unpacked Potrace to `PATH` environment variable (in Windows)

Comment: Doesn't the environment variables reset every time the command prompt is restarted?

Answer (score 1):

According to the product description [BitFonter 3.0](http://www.fontlab.com/photofont/bitfonter/) seems to be able to do that:

> "*Powerful conversion of bitmaps and bitmap fonts from and to Type 1, TrueType and OpenType fonts through integration with FontLab Studio and TypeTool.*"

But US $999 is a little bit expensive to convert just one font.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself searching for these fonts to use with a project I am working on. Cringing at the thought of manually editing all of the glyphs as mentioned in the other answers, I continued to search. Eventually I stumbled across a site which has the original font as well as some newer `.ttf` variants. If you don't care that some of the glyphs have been remapped (they are all still present) this is a nice alternative: [Oldschool PC Fonts](http://int10h.org/oldschool-pc-fonts/). As an added bonus for me these support extended Latin, Greek, Cyrillic and Hebrew scripts plus a bunch of additional glyphs and Unicode symbols.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that you can accomplish it with a simple free tool. http://www.fontlab.com have tools to do it, but they are very expensive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Fontlab is the make of BitFonter.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get autotrace to work, so I wrote A python script to trace black and white images into vector polygons, one for each pixel.

So with a folder of glyph images, you can convert it into a folder of `svg` files.

Then in Inkscape union + simplify path to clean up each glyph. ( might be doable on command line with Inkscape)

Finally import the corresponding `svg` into FontForge for each glyph.

-> script hosted at [gist.gisthub.com](https://gist.github.com/zvodd/18abf5b0a43c115661b5fa791181a221)

```
from PIL import Image
import svgwrite
import os
import argparse


def bmp_to_svg(filename, multiply =1):

    img = Image.open(filename)
    w, h = img.size
    pixel_acc = img.load()

    generated_paths = paths_gen(pixel_acc, w,h, multiply=multiply)

    dwg = svgwrite.Drawing(profile='tiny')
    for path in generated_paths:
        options = path
        kwoptions = {} #{"fill":"black"}
        dwg.add(dwg.polygon(options, **kwoptions))

    #clip_path = dwg.defs.add(dwg.clipPath())
    #clip_path.add(dwg.Rect(insert=(0,0), size=((w*multiply)+1, (h*multiply)+1)))
    return dwg

def paths_gen(pixel_acc, w, h, multiply = 1):
    m = multiply
    paths = []
    for y in range(0,h):
        for x in range(0,w):
            pix = pixel_acc[x,y]
            brightval = sum(pix) /3
            if brightval < 128:
                paths.append([
                        ##top left
                        (x * m, y * m),
                        ##top right
                        ((x+1) * m, y * m),
                        ##bottom right
                        ((x+1) * m, (y+1) * m),
                        ##bottom list
                        ((x) * m, (y+1) * m),
                        ##close back to top left
                        #(x, y), 
                    ])
    return paths


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Script to convert black and white images into vector art')
    parser.add_argument("input_dir")
    parser.add_argument("ouput_dir")
    parser.add_argument("in_ext", default="bmp", help="file extension of images in input folder")
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--multiply", default=1, type=int)
    ## TODO
    #parser.add_argument("-u", "--union", store=True, help="unifies adjecent polgons")
    #parser.add_argument("-s", "--simplify", store=True, help="removes points that are part of a straight line")
    #parser.add_argument("-c", "--compress", store=True, help="same as '--union --simplify'")

    args = parser.parse_args()


    cdir = os.path.abspath(args.input_dir)

    fn_gen = ( x for x in os.listdir(cdir)
                 if x.endswith('.'+args.in_ext)
             )

    for count, filename in enumerate(fn_gen):

        full_filename =  os.path.join(cdir, filename)

        new_fn = "{}_.svg".format(filename)
        new_fullfn =  os.path.join(args.ouput_dir, new_fn)


        svg = bmp_to_svg(full_filename, multiply=args.multiply)
        print "Converted file: '{}'".format(full_filename)
        svg.filename = new_fullfn
        svg.save()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```