# Does iOS support bitmap font in any form to use in UIKit classes?

Tags: ios, fonts, bitmap

Does iOS support bitmap font in any form to use in UIKit classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 3.2, you can add any font you like to the list that UIKit will accept via the [UIAppFonts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW18) info.plist key. It doesn't support any bitmap file types directly, but you can convert a bitmap font to a TTF using methods such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750124/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-font-fon-into-a-truetype-font-ttf) — which involves using an open source piece of software called FontForge along with a bitmap font tracer called autotrace to create (with some manual assistance) a vector description of the bitmap font.

Other answers to that same StackOverflow question report some success with populating a TTF directly with bitmap data. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My main reason was size. I'm making Korean app and average size of Korean vector fonts are 2MB. Seriously, not considerable... I decided to figure out other way.

Comment: I'm unable to find a definitive reference, but it seems you can use either TTF or OTF — the latter may be smaller because you can use a higher order type of curve that often reduces the amount of description you have to store, but I wouldn't expect it'll shrink you to the size of a bitmap font for a language with an alphabet as complicated as Korean. Sorry I couldn't be more help.