# Bitmap Fonts in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, xcode, bitmap, sprite-kit

I've developed a game in Android and it uses Bitmap fonts. I've got the .fnt and .png files associated with the font. Now I'm doing the iPhone version of the same game using spritekit.

Is there a way to use the same font files(fnt and png) as such to reproduce the font there? My XCode version is 6.1.1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820445/does-ios-support-bitmap-font-in-any-form-to-use-in-uikit-classes

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/q/18954144/2158465