# From bitmap font to TrueType font

Tags: android, bitmap, truetype

If I convert a bitmap font (.FON) into a truetype font (.TTF) using FontForge + Autotrace as it is described in this article [How to convert a bitmap font (.FON) into a truetype font (.TTF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750124/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-font-fon-into-a-truetype-font-ttf)

programs and if the bitmap font is colored .. does the converted on (.TFF) will remain colored or it will be converted into black and white font?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a bitmap font (.FON) into a truetype font (.TTF)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750124/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-font-fon-into-a-truetype-font-ttf)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it would be black-and-white, since you are converting a bitmap font to a vector TTF font. The TTF font format does not have a way to specify colour information, hence it will be lost.