# "Terminal" font used in Paint for Windows 8

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I want to use the Terminal font that I've been using for a few headers I made in Paint.

[image: Terminal font example]

I **know** that Java doesn't support bitmap fonts. I'm trying to find a way to get a TrueType version of the above font and I'm getting absolutely nowhere.

The last resort would be to create the rest of my interface titles in Paint, but that's kinda a last resort. I'm not even sure if this is the best StackOverflow question, but I'm open to any solutions, programming-related or otherwise.

Comment: If you're going to do an invisible downvote, at least explain why please. I'd rather not make mistakes in future, and stuff like this doesn't help me learn.

Comment: *"I'm trying to find a way to get a TrueType version of the above font and I'm getting absolutely nowhere."* So you're question is where to get that font? And you don't know if requestion off-site resources is on-topic here? Well, let's check: [Help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. "* ... apparently not.

Comment: As I said, I'm open to programming answers, ways to generate something that approximates it (and even that is hard to search for). Please don't be condescending - if you have time to look up the Help Page for me, you probably have time to actually help me instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows includes Terminal.fon, a bitmap file that has the appearance you want.  You can use the technique [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750124/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-font-fon-into-a-truetype-font-ttf) to convert the FON file to TTF.

Comment: Looks like a bit of a nightmare, but better than anything else I've seen. Appreciated! Will mark as answer if nothing better comes along today.

Comment: Yeah, it just depends on how bad you want it.  Glad I could help.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this free version of Terminus.ttf which might be close enough for you. http://files.ax86.net/terminus-ttf/

Answer (score 0):

Courier is a true type font. Looks like a typewriter font.