# How to use Windows raster (.fon) fonts in JavaFX?

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-2, truetype

For backwards compatibility with the look and feel of existing applications I am looking for support in JavaFX for displaying Windows fonts of type *.fon. Is this possible in JavaFX? I have already tried to use CSS to apply the font named "System" which is defined in 8514sys.fon but it skips that and goes instead to Segoe.

Comment: Can you convert the [.fon to a .ttf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750124/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-font-fon-into-a-truetype-font-ttf) offline and then [embed the ttf with your application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855677/how-to-embed-ttf-fonts-is-javafx-2-2)?

Comment: @jewelsea The file is copyrighted and am I am not able to copy, redistribute, or reverse engineer it. So no.